# MSBuild: Remove Reference to Assembly added via NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

In the process of moving some legacy code from packages.config to PackageReference.

I have a NuGet package (let's say A.nupkg) that has a reference to a different NuPkg (B.nupkg). B.nupkg includes a reference to Foo.dll.

A project referenced A.nupkg in packages.config, but B.nupkg was not (despite being a transitive dependency). The problem is that the project references a drop-in replacement (same namespace and classes, but including bug fixes) for the Foo API in the form of a Foov2.dll

Now with the change to PackageReference the transitive dependency is picked up, Foo.dll is referenced by the project and we end up with ambiguous references between Foo.dll and Foov2.dll. I can't change the NuGet package (wish I could) so I need a workaround.

I tried adding a target that removes the unwanted reference before building it, but I can't find the right spot to put it - or maybe references from NuGets are handled different to normal references:

```
  <Target Name="RemoveOutdatedReferences" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="All references: @(Reference->'%(FileName)'). 
           Sadly no Foo.dll so no wonder I can't remove it."/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Remove="Foo, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Alternatively I also tried to remove the whole transitive NuGet package, but using `<PackageReference Remove="Foo"/>` didn't work either.

Comment: Does `A.dll` (out of `A.nupkg`) also transivitely depend on `Foo.dll`? If no, you could download the NuGet package (e. g. part of the build process, but not as a `PackageReference`) and add a assembly reference to `A.dll

Comment: @mu88 So removing the PackageReference and then manually fiddling around with the dependencies and manually add the references I want? I'm hoping for a at least slightly-less awful MSBuild solution.

Comment: Well without further knowledge of the NuGet package's content (assemblies and their dependencies), it's hard to provide a better solution.

Comment: @mu88 Just assume a normal nupkg with a A.dll with a reference to the Foo.dll (but you can work around that with binding redirects to the Foov2.dll which seems to be working fine with packages.config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like PackageReference Alias feature is designed specifically for scenarios of namespace collisions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#packagereference-aliases

> In some rare instances different packages will contain classes in the
> same namespace. Starting with NuGet 5.7 & Visual Studio 2019 Update 7,
> equivalent to ProjectReference, PackageReference supports Aliases. By
> default no aliases are provided. When an alias is specified, all
> assemblies coming from the annotated package with need to be
> referenced with an alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove reference in custom target

```
<Target Name="CustomBeforeBuild" AfterTargets="ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild">
    <ItemGroup> 
      <ReferenceToBeRemoved Include="@(Reference)" Condition="'%(Reference.PathInPackage)' == 'lib/netstandard2.0/UnneedDll.dll'" />
      <Reference Remove="@(ReferenceToBeRemoved)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="### References to remove: @(ReferenceToBeRemoved) ###" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Awesome - fixed my issue nicely.

Answer (score 0):

According to our little discussion, the only option so far I see is to create a custom NuGet package which encapsulates `A.nupkg` without its dependencies:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>My.Wrapper.Around.A<PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.0<PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="A" Version="x.y.z">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets), `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` should prevent all transitive dependencies from `A.nupkg` flowing up to the consumer.

And in your target project:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="My.Wrapper.Around.A" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Foov2" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: But doesn't there have to be a target/task where the NuGet assemblies are added to the project's references? Are you saying this is somewhat special cased in MSBuild or just that you don't know the correct targets/tasks either?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean. About which assembly are you talking? `A.dll`? Or `Foov2.dll`?

Comment: Any dll that's integrated via PackageReference. I imagine there's a msbuild task that takes those dlls and metadata and adds it to the projects References itemgroup. Are you saying that's not how this works or simply that you don't know either?

Comment: I don't know how these details are working under the hood. Could be MSBuild, could be `csc.exe` (Compiler). But with my approach, I'd hope that you don't need this magic of manually removing dependencies anymore.